# Delayed job run_at not running at correct time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a couple jobs that are set via `after_create` hook of an object. During my tests, i have been saving the object so one job fires around 5 minutes later, and one job 10 minutes later (using two attributes of the model that are datetime). The problem is, both seem to execute right away. If i create the object setting the two date values 24 hours in the future, it seems to wait. So I'm wondering if the time the worker thinks it is, is different then what the server is. Is there a way to make sure the delayed_job worker is in sync?

Here's the code for queueing the jobs:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(CharityProductCreateJob.new(self.id, shop.id), 0, self.start_date)
Delayed::Job.enqueue(CharityProductCreateJob.new(self.id, shop.id), 0, self.end_date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may answer your question http://www.gregbenedict.com/2009/08/19/is-delayed-job-run_at-datetime-giving-you-fits/

Comment: I had run into that search result myself. I tried something like this, but no luck: `Delayed::Job.enqueue(CharityProductCreateJob.new(self.id, shop.id), 0, self.start_date.utc)`

Comment: Just came back to this question to select an answer. The above is partly correct for my situation. One thing to check is see what time you default to in the application.rb file. I updated that to Eastern standard, and then call .utc, like in my above comment.